# Pass runtime parameters in PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I have a below powerShell script that creates homedrive for user,

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 2>&1 | Write-Host; 
if($?)
{

$homeDir = "\\CORP.com\HOME\Jdoe";
$user = "jdoe";
$domain = "Corp";

New-Item "$homeDir" -type directory;

$acl = Get-Acl "$homeDir";
$permission = "$domain\$user","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow";
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission;

$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule);

$acl | Set-Acl "$homeDir";
}
```

Values within $homeDir and $User will be passed on runtime basis.

How to execute above script along with pass runtime values in $homeDir and $User attribute.

I have tried to execute,

`. 'C:\hd.ps1' $homeDir = "\\CORP.com\HOME\test" $user = "test" ;` without success.

Can anyone guide, what i am doing incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
param(
$homeDir,
$user
)
```

At the top of the script and call using

```
Powershell -File "C:\hd.ps1" -homeDir "\\CORP.com\HOME\test" -user "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 2>&1 | Write-Host;
```

If you are on the DC doing this or if you have the RSAT tools on your workstation, if you are on PowerShell v3+ or higher, this gets auto loaded the moment you use an AD cmdlet.

Also never user Write-Host for anything that you plan to need later. It empties / clears the buffer. Write-Host is only  good for text coloring or other formatting needs in s

Make this a collection from a file for example and just read it in. I'm just using a list here:

```
$UserFile = @'
Property,Value
homeDir,\\CORP.com\HOME\Jdoe
user,jdoe
Targetdomain,Corp
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Results

Property     Value               
--------     -----               
homeDir      \\CORP.com\HOME\Jdoe
user         jdoe                
Targetdomain Corp
```

If you are doing this from a remote machine, then you cannot use local varibles in a remote session unless you set its scope.

```
Get-Help about_remote_variables -Full
```

[About Remote Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6)

> LONG DESCRIPTION
>
> You can use variables in commands that you run on remote
>   computers.Simply assign a value to the variable and then use the
>   variable inplace of the value.
>
> By default, the variables in remote commands are assumed to be
>   definedin the session in which the command runs. You can also use
>   variablesthat are defined in the local session, but you must identify
>   them aslocal variables in the command.
>
> USING LOCAL VARIABLES
>
> You can also use local variables in remote commands, but you
>   mustindicate that the variable is defined in the local session.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using
>   scopemodifier to identify a local variable in a remote command.

The semi-colons are not needed in PowerShell, unless the items are on the same line.

You cannot call this code this way...

```
'C:\hd.ps1' $homeDir = "\\CORP.com\HOME\test" $user = "test"
```

... since you did not specify any params in your code.

So, something like this...

***Note: I am not in a position to test this... please do only in a test environment***
So this is off the cuff...

```
ForEach($UserLine in $UserFile)
{
    New-Item $UserLine.homeDir -type directory

    $acl = Get-Acl $UserLine.homeDir
    $permission = ($Using:UserLine.Targetdomain + '\' + $Using:UserLine.user),'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
    $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission

    $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)

    $acl | Set-Acl $Using:UserLine.homeDir
}
```

If you want this to be a parameterized function, then this.,.

```
Function New-ADUserHomeDirSettings
{
    [cmdletbinding()]

    Param
    (
        [string]$homeDir,
        [string]$user,
        [string]$Targetdomain
    )

    $acl = Get-Acl $UserLine.homeDir
    $permission = ($Using:UserLine.Targetdomain + '\' + $Using:UserLine.user),'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
    $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission

    $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)

    $acl | Set-Acl $Using:UserLine.homeDir
}

New-ADUserHomeDirSettings -homeDir '' -user '' -Targetdomain ''
```